# Looking for an OR gate for electric lines

Tags: electrical, switch

I need a box that will input two 110v electric lines and output one 110v line. If either input is on I want output line to be on (like an "OR" gate).

Comment: Why do you want this?  Are you trying to transfer power to some device that needs power all the time, or?

Comment: Agreed -- this is what we call an "XY" question. Telling us what problem you are trying to solve (X) will produce better answers than asking us how to implement a pre-selected solution (Y).

Comment: I two thermostats that remotely measure temperature under my water pipes. They are set to turn on an electric outlet so that it's live when the temperature drops below 40 degrees. I have one fan that I want to start when either of the outlets are live. Thanks

Comment: So all you need really is an old school *switch loop* with 2 switches in parallel on the switch loop. Standard switch loop, but after you get to the endpoint (switch), simply continue to another switch also.  Power goes supply -> outlet -> switch1 -> switch2.   If you need to go the other sequence that's fine but you'll need /3 between the switche/stats.

Answer (score 3):

As per comments:

**If the 120VAC<sup>*</sup> is from the same circuit breaker,** A simple junction (tie all three hot wires together, all three neutral  wires together, and all three ground wires together in a junction box, with wire nuts or Wagos or whatever) will do that.

The ground wires need to also be connected to the junction box, if it's metal (and metal is a superior, and usually less expensive, junction box, so it should be metal, IMHO.)

**If the source is from different circuits,** you must switch both the hot and the neutral, because you cannot join the neutrals from two different circuits.

An automatic transfer switch would be an off-the-shelf means of getting that, so it might not void your insurance (if you get a listed one, not whatever random unlisted import is cheapest.) You will have to specifically pick one that switches neutral. If you build something yourself from parts, make sure that wherever you are using it won't be likely to require finding out that your insurance considers it a "get out of paying claims free" card.

In most cases it is less expensive to maintain a listed configuration with a UPS, but that depends on the unknown use case.

<sup>*</sup>*USA/Canada split-phase has been 120VAC for 50 years or more. It was 115 for a while before that, and 110 is ancient.*

Comment: You might add that this only works if the hots are on the same phase (which is only guaranteed if they are fed from the same circuit breaker).

Comment: Good point, @BartvanIngenSchenau, what happens if the hots come from different breakers? You turn one off, but the box & device(s) connected downstream are still hot.

Comment: If the hots come from different breakers, you need to switch both the hots and the neutrals.

Comment: These are both on the same circuit so I'll use your first solution. I'm going to wire them to an outlet in a metal box as you described. Will it be okay to use a GFCI outlet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something, you can do that with a relay.  The coil is wired to Line-A.  And Normally-Open Contact is wired to Line-A.  Line-B is wired to Normally-Closed contact.

- When LineA has power, the output is connected to LineA.
- If LineA has no power, the output is connected to LineB.
- If LineB has no power either, the output wont have any power either.